Scope of Mathematica for verifying a textbook level attempted proof
I'm not an expert in Mathematica but use it often for routine things .Of late I got immenesley interested in the capabilities of Mathematica for verifying proofs, especially those that are predominantly computational and involve applying various lemmas and theorems.
As  most of us here might most probably   agree that while Mathematica excels at executing complex calculations, the process of algorithmically verifying a mathematical proof can be quite challenging. This is especially true for proofs that are not purely algorithmic but involve logical deductions based on the application of theorems and lemmas.
Consider, for instance, a proof that calculates the bounds on the roots of a polynomial, where these bounds are contingent upon certain conditions applied to the roots, and involves using known bounds or results from theorems such as the Eneström-Kakeya Theorem.
How, if at all, can Mathematica be used to verify the steps of such a proof? Is there a framework or methodology within Mathematica that assists in:
Checking the logical consistency and validity of each step in the proof.
Verifying the computational steps that involve applying specific lemmas or theorems to calculate bounds.
Handling proofs that require a mix of computational rigor and theoretical deductions.
I'm looking for insights, experiences, or even specific functionalities within Mathematica that could aid in the verification of such proofs. Has anyone tackled similar challenges, and if so, what approaches did you find effective?
As a specific example Consider a the lemma
\begin{equation}
a_0, a_1, \ldots, a_q, a_{q+1}, \ldots, a_p, a_{p+1}, \ldots, a_n
\end{equation}
where
\begin{align}
a_{q-1} &\geqslant a_{q-2} \geqslant \ldots \geqslant a_0, \\
a_n &\geqslant a_{n-1} \ldots \geqslant a_{p+1}, 
\end{align}
and let
\begin{equation}
M_{p, q} = \sum_{j=q}^{p+1}\left|a_{j}-a_{j-1}\right|, p \geq q,q \geq 1.
\end{equation}
Then,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j=1}^n\left|a_{j}-a_{j-1}\right| = (a_q - a_0)  + M_{p, q}  + (a_n - a_{p+1}).
\end{equation}
Using this I have obtained the theorem  :
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
P(z) &= \underbrace{(a_{n} z^{n} + a_{n-1} z^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{p+1} z^{p+1})}_{\text{monotonic coefficients}} 
 + \underbrace{( a_p z^p +a_{p-1} z^{p-1} + \cdots + a_{q} z^{q})}_{\text{free coefficients}} \\
&\phantom{=} + \underbrace{(a_{q-1} z^{q-1} + \cdots + a_{1} z + a_{0})}_{\text{monotonic coefficients}}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
be a polynomial of degree ( n ) with the coefficients satisfying the conditions:
\begin{align*}
a_{n} &\geq a_{n-1} \geq \cdots \geq a_{p+1}, \quad p \geq q \\
a_{q-1} &\geq a_{q-2} \geq \cdots \geq a_0
\end{align*}
and
\begin{equation*}
M_{p,q} = \sum_{j=q}^{p+1} |a_{j}-a_{j-1}|
\end{equation*}
Then,  all the zeros of  ( P(z) ) whose modulus exceeds 1 lie in the disc:
\begin{equation*}
|z| \leq \frac{(a_{q-1} - a_0)  + M_{p, q}  + (a_n - a_{p+1})+|a_0|}{|a_n|}
\end{equation*}How do I verify the steps of the proof,which is mostly step by step  computations ?
Thank you for your time and insights.

PS: The spirit of question and query is very general in the context of leveraging the power of Mathematica in mathematics .The above specific example only serves as an illustring instance for what am trying to explore in general

Mathematica's 'proof' system will not work so well here because you have free variable $n$ . I haven't tried, but I imagine it would be very hard to specify all of this. You are better off with Lean / Coq which are proof assistants.
